# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable for printing a dictionary inside a while loop

Tags: python

I'm having issues with a codeword game (also known as replace the characters) program I'm writing and I keep getting the error 'str' object is not callable. This is my code (just the part of the while loop which relates to this dictionary:

```
used_pairings = {}

while.....:
    used_pairings[guesschar] = guessletter
    print = ("At this point you can decide whether to delete a character-letter pairing.")
    used_pairings_choice = input("Type 1 to delete a pairing or ENTER to carry on: ")
    if used_pairings_choice == "1":
        print ("These are your pairings so far:")
        print (used_pairings)
    else:
        print ("Continuing program.")
```

This is the error I get:

```
"Codeword.py", line 79, in <module>
    print ("These are your pairings so far:")
TypeError: 'str' object not callable
```

I'm completely at odds as to what this means and why I get this error message so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3? What's going on with the `while.......`?

Comment: It's python 3.3.3 and the while.... is the rest of the program where the things for replacing the characters happens (this works perfectly)

Comment: Three upvotes for a typo, seriously? We have a close reason for that, please use it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using python 3+ `print` is a function. When you do `print = ("At this point you can decide whether to delete a character-letter pairing.")` you are overriding the `print` builtin function with a string. So just removing the `=` from that line should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is, `print` variable declaration.

```
print = ("At this point you can decide whether to delete a character-letter pairing.")
```

after this statement `print` function of python change to `print` variable in `str` (STRING).

Please change variable name and try your code.

Comment: Why did I do that, eh?

Comment: Thanks it works fine with the changes you guys suggested.